# How can I get information about remote directories mounted through sshfs?

Tags: mount, sshfs

If I mount a directory from a remote server on my local machine using `sshfs`, how can I find out such details as:

- Whether any such mount is currently mounted;
- The user who mounted it;
- The remote and local directories;
- The time it was mounted at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the remote directory is mounted, it will be listed in the output of `mount`. That contains most of the information you need:

```
$ mount -t fuse.sshfs 
terdon@123.456.7.8:/remote/path/dir/ on /home/terdon/foo type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1001,group_id=1001)
```

With that in mind, you could write a little script that parses the output and gives you most of the details:

```
$ mount -t fuse.sshfs | 
    perl -ne '/.+?@(\S+?):(.+?)\s+on\s+(.+)\s+type.*user_id=(\d+)/; 
    print "Remote host: $1\nRemote dir: $2\nLocal dir: $3\nLocal user: $4\n"'
Remote host: 139.124.66.43
Remote dir: /cobelix/terdon/research/
Local dir: /home/terdon/haha
Local user: 1001
```

This can be made into a shell function or script, extended to show user name instead of UID and extracting the time from `ps`. This assumes you don't need milliseconds accuracy since the output of `ps` refers to when the command was launched and not necessarily when the mount operation ended.

```bash
sshfs_info(){
    mount -t fuse.sshfs | head -n1 |
    perl -ne '/.+?@(\S+?):(.+)(?= on\s+\/)(.+)\s+type.*user_id=(\d+)/; 
     print "Remote host: $1\nRemote dir: $2\nLocal dir: $3\nLocal user: " . 
     `grep  :1001: /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1` '
    printf "Elapsed time: %s\n" $(ps -p $(pgrep -f sftp | head -n1) o etime=)
    }
```

If you add the function above to your shell's initialization file (e.g. `~/.bashrc` for bash), you can then run:

```
$ sshfs_info
Remote host: 123.456.7.8
Remote dir: /remote/path/dir
Local dir: /home/terdon/foo
Local user: terdon
Elapsed time: 44:16
```

Note that this assumes only a single sftp instance is running. If you need to deal with multiple instances, use this one instead:

```bash
sshfs_info(){
## A counter, just to know whether a separator should be printed
c=0
## Get the mounts
mount -t fuse.sshfs | grep -oP '^.+?@\S+?:\K.+(?= on /)' |
# Iterate over them
    while read mount
    do
    ## Get the details of this mount. 
    mount | grep -w "$mount" |
        perl -ne '/.+?@(\S+?):(.+)\s+on\s+(.+)\s+type.*user_id=(\d+)/; 
              print "Remote host: $1\nRemote dir: $2\nLocal dir: $3\nLocal user: " . 
              `grep  :1001: /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1` '
    printf "Elapsed time: %s\n" "$(ps -p $(pgrep -f "$mount") o etime=)"
    ## Increment the counter
    let c++;
    ## Separate the entries if more than one mount was found
    [[ $c > 0 ]] && echo "---"

    done
}
```

The output looks like:

```
$ sshfs_info 
Remote host: 123.456.7.8
Remote dir: /remote/path/foobar/
Local dir: /home/terdon/baz
Local user: terdon
Elapsed time:    01:53:26
---
Remote host: 123.456.7.8
Remote dir: /remote/path/foo/
Local dir: /home/terdon/bar
Local user: terdon
Elapsed time:    01:00:39
---
Remote host: 123.456.7.8
Remote dir: /remote/path/bar/
Local dir: /home/terdon/baz
Local user: terdon
Elapsed time:       53:57
---
Remote host: 123.456.7.8
Remote dir: /remote/path/ho on ho
Local dir: /home/terdon/a type of dir
Local user: terdon
Elapsed time:       44:24
---
```

As you can see in the example above, it can deal with directory names containing spaces as well.

Finally, note that this is not 100% portable. It should work on any system that has the GNU toolset (any Linux distribution, for example) but it won't work on non-GNU systems because it's using features specific to GNU grep.